# ADF visualizations: Retrieve current managed bean

Tags: java, jdeveloper, oracle-adf

I'm building a small ADF application using data visualizations and ran into a problem.

I have a session scoped managed bean, named `map_action`, which is used to pass data from a `<dvt:map>` to a sql query inside a DataControl by its property `country`.

This query uses a bind variable named `location` in its `where` clause. And the bind variable takes its value from a Groovy expression:

`adf.context.sessionScope.map_action.country`

This has one problem. Even though the value of `map_action.country` changes, the bind variable always uses the first value.

Is there any way to make `location` take the value of `map_action.country`?  It looks like it is reading a cached value.

Perhaps the Groovy expression is not correct. Is there any way to message the current `map_action` instance?

Answer (score 1):

As for the task , make an object of the View Object(VO)(assumig you using BC layer) and then set the bind variable by using setNamedWhereClause() function and execute the query.

As you said you have session scope bean, you can create an intialization function to be called before the query is executed and set the params there.

I hope this solves the problem.

Thanks